# Get multi relational record - laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have these tables

**Assessment**

```
 - ID (PK)
```

**Questionnaire**

```
 - ID (PK)
 - assessment_id(FK)
```

**QuestionGroup**

```
 - ID (PK)
 - questionnaire_id(FK)
```

**Question**

```
 - ID (PK)
 - group_id(FK)
 - questionnaire_id(FK)
```

They are all related ManyToOne
 Assessment can have multiple questionnaires.
 Questionnaire can have multiple QuestionGroups
 QuestionGroups can have multiple Questions.

I want to Eloquently query a assessment and get all related questionnaires, groups and questions.

I have setup my model relations as follows:

**ASSESSMENT**

```
public function Questionnaires()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Questionnaire', 'assessment_id');
}
```

**QUESTIONNAIRE**

```
public function question_groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\QuestionGroup', 'questionnaire_id')->with('questions');
}
```

**QuestionGroup**

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Question', 'group_id');
}
```

Is there a way to just query for the `assessment` record and get all subsequent relational records aswell?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep The author is a SO user @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
    $assessment = Assessment::with(['questionnaires'=>function($qstnr){$qstnr->whereNull('deleted_at');}])
        ->with(['questionnaires.question_groups'=>function($group){$group->whereNull('deleted_at');}])
        ->where('assessment.admission_id',  $admissionId)
        ->orderBy('assessment.day_in_unit','desc')
        ->first();
    if($assessment){
        $assessment = $assessment->toArray();
    }
```